# Use MySQL variables with Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I am trying to grab max of 4 rows for each distinct value. This query I have works.

`SET @currcount = NULL, @currvalue = NULL;
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
        *, 
        @currcount := IF(@currvalue = quantity, @currcount + 1, 1) AS rank,
        @currvalue := quantity AS whatever
    FROM wines
    where restaurant_id = 16 and owner_id is null 
    ORDER BY quantity DESC
) AS x WHERE rank <= 4`

But now I can't get it to work with Sequelize. Can I use @variable in Sequelize?

Has anyone done this? Or am I going to have to just use a raw query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but put your 2 queries in one like this
and try it with : **sequelize.query(.....**

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
        *, 
        @currcount := IF(@currvalue = quantity, @currcount + 1, 1) AS rank,
        @currvalue := quantity AS whatever
    FROM wines
    where restaurant_id = 16 and owner_id is null 
    ORDER BY quantity DESC
) AS x 
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @currcount := NULL, @currvalue := NULL) as parameter
WHERE rank <= 4;
```